# Как лучше разделить решение?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git

Есть решение: server(консоль), client(wpf) и admin(wpf). Текущее решение включает в себя 25 проектов ~25000 строк. Общие элементы(контролы, конвертеры и.т.п) между клиентом и админом находятся в отдельных модулях. В текущем состоянии все работает, но поставили задачу сделать версию без сервера и админки, т.е сухой клиент.

Сам вопрос: как лучше реализовать эту облегченную версию? Как бы вы поступили? Наверное без кода тяжело сказать, но опубликовать его не могу.

Придумал пока что 2 варианта:

1. Сделать новую ветку от текущей и повырезать там ~15 ненужных проектов и параллельно вести ее с основной. Вроде бы все ок, но как не запутаться между кодом внутри оставшихся библиотек(ui клиент и его сервисы) в этой ветке с основной dev веткой, т.е синхронизировать изменения там и тут. Постоянно прыгать между ветками и выгружать/загружать по 15 проектов? Visual Studio не станет плохо?
2. Добавить новый wpf проект к текущим и уже в нем подключить нужные проекты. Вроде бы ок, но другие необходимые библиотеки частично связаны с отправкой данных серверу через единую общую. Я могу не подключать этот функционал, но лишний неиспользуемый код мне не нравится.

Comment: Можно создать пустое решение и добавить в него существующие проекты связанные с клиентской частью. В итоге проекты связанные с клиентской частью будут в единственном экземпляре, но в 2-х разных решениях.

Comment: ¿Судя по описанию, все 25 проектов запиханы в один-единственный гит репозиторий?

Comment: @user7860670 именно так. Скрин решения: https://i.imgur.com/K4jcBjR.png Modules - части prism.

Comment: @user7860670 почти мой 2й вариант получается.

Comment: Ну тогда предлагаю разделить один разжиревший репозиторий на несколько меньших. Проект = гит репозиторий = единица повторного использования кода. Тогда можно будет без проблем сделать второе решение с нужным ему набором проектов для клиента или переиспользовать эти проекты где-то еще.

Comment: @user7860670 звучит логично про один проект - один репозиторий, но, наверное, для меня черезчур модульность. Раньше максимум разбивал на 3 репозитория, но не на десятки)

А так облегченный клиент будет использовать практически весь ui обычного, вырезая серверную часть, а это от силы 10%. Возможно в таком случае обычный клиент должен наследовать облегченный, добавляя сетевео взаимодействие.

Большинство модулей - 2 view,vm 1-2 сервиса, несколько дополнительных моделей и все. В целом, очень маленькие.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Мой предыдущий комментарий еще имел такой смыл, что выделения отдельного проекта и репозитория не должно происходить, если нет необходимости в повторном использовании. Вот если у вас там модуль `Client.Common` не будет где-то использован повторно, то и не надо было выделять его в отдельный проект. И репозиториев в итоге будет не так много.

Comment: `поставили задачу сделать версию без сервера и админки` - чтобы открыть эту часть кода?

Comment: @ESkri немного не понял вопроса. Сейчас клиент генерирует некую информацию, отображает ее у пользователя и отдает ее серверу. Админ получают информацию от сервера обо всех клиентах. Надо: полностью убрать сервер и админ, т.е, клиент просто генерирует информацию, показывает ее пользователю и никуда не отдает.

Comment: и зачем для этого создавать отдельный репозиторий?  почему на клиенте не ввести опцию, которая будет при сборке клиента включать или выключать зависимость клиента от других частей?

Comment: скрипт сборки передаёт разные значения переменных для условной компиляции, а внутри проекта у вас `#if` `#endif`

Comment: @ESkri думал на счет директив, но они работаю в xaml?